# How do I solve this limit without the L'hopital's rule?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \frac{ 2x^2-5x+2 }{ \sqrt{2+x}-\sqrt{2x} }$$

Thanks

Comment: I'd guess multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{2+x}+\sqrt{2x}$ will help.

Comment: I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Factor $2x^2-5x+2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that $$2x^2-5x+2=(2x-1)(x-2)$$ and we have by multiplication of numerator and denominator with $\sqrt{2+x}+\sqrt{2x}$ the following term
$$\frac{(2x-1)(x-2)(\sqrt{2+x}+\sqrt{2x})}{-(x-2)}$$

Comment: I forgot that you can make (x-1/2) to (2x-1). Thanks.